# How would teaching during the last year of a postdoc be perceived on the academic job market?

Tags: teaching, postdocs, faculty-application

How would large and small research schools, master's only schools, and liberal arts schools all look at a post-doc who did 5 years of research and a 6th year of teaching + post-doc at ~50/50? This would be in physics if that matters.

Comment: Do you mean 5 years of research only followed by 1 year of teaching only, or do you mean 5 years of research only followed by 1 year of teaching + research? And are those at the same institution or separate institutions?

Comment: the 6th year is teaching and post-doc research. The teaching would be at a different institution than the post-doc

Comment: I'm assuming you're asking about applying for faculty positions, so I tagged it as such. If not, please [edit] to clarify what kind of jobs you are asking about.

Answer (score 3):

In my, undergraduate-only department we aren't looking for teaching experience as a check box on the incoming CVs, we're looking for evidence that the candidate *likes* teaching. Because that's what we're hiring someone to do. Of course, if you haven't logged some time in the classroom then there is no way for you to know, but we are perfectly willing to listen to *"When I was a TA ..."* stories to get a sense of how the candidate thinks and feels about teaching.

And of course, we're looking for a research background that will give you a chance of doing something here, but with five years of post-doctoral research you look good on paper. We'd want to hear you talk about getting some research done with limited resources.

Comment: A _big_ problem with the CV-filler scenario for the OP is that faculty job searches often initiate in or before the fall of the 6th year; that is to say, having taught for not even half a semester, the OP would have really little credibility if he/she tries to tell "When I was a TA" stories.